Ionic ToastController not showing toast after npm run build
The issue is: Using ToastController after build doesn't shows the toast. Its working as expected with npm run serve, but not when builded. Seems like never reaching the point of console.log('Message Toast Service 3');.


 export class MessageToastService {
  toastController = inject(ToastController);

  async show(message?: string, duration: number = 3000, error?: Error ) {
    console.log ('Message Toast 1');
    if (!message && error) {
      message = error.message;
    }
    console.log ('Message Toast 2');

    try {
      const toast = await this.toastController.create({
        message: message,
        duration: duration,
        position: 'bottom',
        color: 'warning',
      });

      console.log ('Message Toast Service 3');
      await toast.present();
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

}
  




is there any error in console?

no there is no error , and if I replace it  with for example PopController or AlertController again its working correctly . There is one warning on from the build , but don't think its related :
▲ [WARNING] The glob pattern import("./**/.entry.js") did not match any files [empty-glob]
node_modules/@stencil/core/internal/client/index.js:82:2:
  82 │   `./${bundleId}.entry.js${BUILD4.hotModuleReplacement && hmrVersi...
     ╵   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


I discovered if add an option "optimization": false for the build in angular.json its working correctly , but don't think this is acceptable as solution

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

I found the same as Dimitar.  The optimization is breaking more than just Toast, I'm losing other alerts as well.  Just a workaround as build size jumps without optimizing.
add/modify inside angular.json -> build -> configurations -> production:
"optimization": false
